# Building a Complex Search Filter based on Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Wondering if there is a linq solution to this complex situation; for example, Customer selects *Color: red, Size: large, Type: Cotton*. If I know for sure that a Customer would select these filters each single time, I would just do something like this:

```
var shirts = ListOfShirts.Where(i=> i.Color.Contains("red") && Size.Contains("Large") && Type.Contains("Cotton"));
```

Here is the current structure and an action method that accepts a number of filters from the view:

**Classes**:

```
public partial class Shirt {
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public string Color  { get; set; }
   public string Size { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedFilter {
   public string Name { get; set; } // Filter Menu Title
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Filter(IList<SelectedFilter> selectedFilters) {
       var model = new List<Shirt>();
       Shirt ListOfShirts = db.GetAllShirts();
       var groups = selectedFilters.GroupBy(i => i.Name);

            foreach (var g in groups)
            {
                var GroupName = g.FirstOrDefault().name;
                var GroupValues = g.Select(i => i.value).ToList();

                if (g.FirstOrDefault().name == "Color")
                {
                    model = ListOfShirts.Where(i => GroupValues.Contains(i.Color)).ToList();
                }
                else if (g.FirstOrDefault().name == "Size")
                {
                    model = ListOfShirts.Where(i => GroupValues.Contains(i.Size)).ToList();
                }
                else if (g.FirstOrDefault().name == "Type")
                {
                    model = ListOfShirts.Where(i => GroupValues.Contains(i.Type)).ToList();
                }
            }
   }
```

Comment: Your question is, basically, how to build an expression which accesses the property based on its name?

Comment: Without writing it for you, take a look at expression trees: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx , which is one of the more elegant ways to do it.  Otherwise just do deductive reasoning in your where clause(s).

Comment: *If I know for sure that a Customer would select these filters each single time, I would just do something like this* OK, what's the question? I expect something like, *but...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (brutal) way to do it:

```
public ActionResult Filter(IList<SelectedFilter> selectedFilters) {
       var model = new List<Shirt>();
       IEnumerable<Shirt> ListOfShirts = db.GetAllShirts();

        IEnumerable<Shirt> filteredListOfShirts = ListOfShirts
           .Where(shirt => {
               return (
                    (selectedFilters.Any(filter => filter.Name == "Color" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Value)) ? // is Color filter set?
                        selectedFilters.Any(filter =>
                        {
                            return (filter.Name == "Color" && shirt.Color == filter.Value);
                            }) : true)
                    &&
                    (selectedFilters.Any(filter => filter.Name == "Size" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Value)) ? // is Size filter set?
                        selectedFilters.Any(filter =>
                       {
                           return (filter.Name == "Size" && shirt.Size == filter.Value);
                       }) : true)
                    &&
                    (selectedFilters.Any(filter => filter.Name == "Type" && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Value)) ? // is Type filter set?
                        selectedFilters.Any(filter =>
                        {
                            return (filter.Name == "Type" && shirt.Type == filter.Value);
                        }) : true)
                    );
               });

        model = filteredListOfShirts.ToList();

   }
```

That should also work if you have multiple filter values with same name

```
{Name="Color",Value="Red"},{Name="Color",Value="Blue"}
```

Comment: Just got a chance to try this approach, and it looked promising; however, it does not work well when selecting values that belong to different filters at the same time. For example, if I would to select Color Red, then select Type Cotton, I end up with Type Cotton only...etc

Comment: I edited the code and added parentheses around each of the the "is filter set". Seems that without them, other filters were not validated.

Comment: Just tried the edited code, and it does not seem to be working because it is returning all items regardless any filter.

Comment: I will keep trying, but is this supposed to be reductive reasoning or else?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method which checks to see if a given `Shirt` is in a filter, then use `All` to check for each one.

```
public static void Filter(IList<SelectedFilter> selectedFilters)
{
    var filters = selectedFilters
        .GroupBy(i => i.Name);

    var filteredShirts = db
        .GetAllShirts()
        .Where(shirt => filters.All(filter => ShirtInFilter(filter, shirt)));
}

public static bool ShirtInFilter(
    IGrouping<string, SelectedFilter> filter,
    Shirt shirt)
{
    var values = filter.Select(i => i.Value);

    switch (filter.Key)
    {
        case "Color":
            return values.Contains(shirt.Color);
        case "Size":
            return values.Contains(shirt.Size);
        case "Type":
            return values.Contains(shirt.Type);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

The `switch` could be eliminated if you want to access properties using reflection, but that seems like overkill for your use case.

Comment: Excellent approach and works well. However, I wonder how to tweak it to make it a reductive filtering approach? Meaning that selecting Color Red and Then Type Cotton would bring "only" Red shirts that is of type Cotton. This approach so far brings all red shirts and all shirts of type cotton

Comment: @usefulBee Ahh, I misunderstood your question. Give my updated answer a whirl and see if it does what you need.

Comment: I verified the updated answer, and it works like charm! It was a tough decision to award the answer to another approach, just because of its clarity; however, I truly appreciate you sharing your top notch skills and 4 dimension mind with others. Please do not stop!